# Adding Caliburn Micro Screen(UserControl) to a Canvas in WPF MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, caliburn.micro

I am using `Caliburn Micro` in my Project and i have many UserControls and thier viewmodel inherited from `PropertyChangedBase`, i want this UserControl to be added to a Canvas in my ShellView. I dont want to use `IWindowManager` from showing Windows instead i want them to get added in a Canvas.

Please help. How can i do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `ContentControl` within your `ShellView` you can hook into the View-ViewModel binding process of Caliburn.Micro.

I assume that in your `ShellViewModel` you have a bunch of properties exposed that are types of `ViewModel`. If you place a `ContentControl` in your `ShellView` (this could be on/as a child of `Canvas` if that is the container you wish to use to layout your Shell), and then name that control with the name of the property in your `ShellViewModel` you wish it to be bound to, then Caliburn's `ViewModelBinder` will do the rest for you.

As an example say you have a VM called `FizzViewModel` and a matching View called `FizzView` (which is just a `UserControl`) and you want `FizzView` to appear on your `ShellView` you could do something like the following...

A stripped back `ShellViewModel`

```
public class ShellViewModel : Screen, IShell
{
    public ShellViewModel(FizzViewModel theFizz)
    {
        TheFizz = theFizz;
    }

    public FizzViewModel TheFizz { get; set; }
}
```

And its matching `ShellView`

```
<UserControl x:Class="ANamespace.ShellView">
    <Canvas> 
        <ContentControl x:Name="TheFizz"></ContentControl>
    </Canvas> 
</UserControl>
```

Here because the `ContentControl` is named TheFizz, it will be bound by Caliburn to the property with that name on your VM (the one of type `FizzViewModel`)

Doing this means you don't have to laydown your `UserControl`'s  using their true types on your `ShellView`, you let Caliburn do the work for you via conventions (which all so means its easy to swap out the type TheFizz if you just add a little more interface indirection).

#### UPDATE

From the extra information you have provided in the comments, I can now see you are actually looking at a problem that requires an ItemsControl.

The default `DataTemplate` Caliburn uses looks like the following

```
<DataTemplate xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  
              xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro">  
    <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}"   
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"  
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />  
</DataTemplate>
```

You will notice that it uses a `ContentControl`, which has some advantages as I have discussed above. Basically what this will do is allow Caliburn to provide `DataTemplateSelector` like behaviour to the items in your `ItemsControl`. So you can add VMs of different types to the collection your `ItemsControl` is bound to and this default `DataTemplate` will resolve the type of View to use to display it. The following demos a very simple example of how you can achieve what you want.

First the ShellViewModel, take note of the `BindableCollection` named Items

```
[Export(typeof(IShell))]
public class ShellViewModel : IShell 
{
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        Items = new BindableCollection<Screen>();
        _rand = new Random();
    }

    public BindableCollection<Screen> Items { get; set; }

    private Random _rand;

    public void AddItem()
    {
        var next = _rand.Next(3);
        var mPosition = System.Windows.Input.Mouse.GetPosition(App.Current.MainWindow);
        switch (next)
        {
            case 0:
                {
                    Items.Add(new BlueViewModel
                        {
                            X = mPosition.X,
                            Y = mPosition.Y,
                        });
                    break;
                }

            case 1:
                {
                    Items.Add(new RedViewModel
                    {
                        X = mPosition.X,
                        Y = mPosition.Y,
                    });
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    Items.Add(new GreenViewModel
                    {
                        X = mPosition.X,
                        Y = mPosition.Y,
                    });
                    break;
                }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And then a few dummy VM types that you want to display in your Shell. These could be/do anything you like:

```
public abstract class SquareViewModel : Screen
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}

public class BlueViewModel : SquareViewModel
{

}

public class RedViewModel : SquareViewModel
{

}

public class GreenViewModel : SquareViewModel
{

}
```

Now a ShellView, note the ItemsControl which binds to the Items property on your ShellViewModel

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cal="clr-namespace:Caliburn.Micro;assembly=Caliburn.Micro">

<Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ItemsControl x:Name="Items"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseLeftButtonUp] = [Action AddItem()]"
                            Background="Transparent"></Canvas>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X}" />
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y}" />
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And an example of a `UserControl` that will be used to display the `GreenViewModel`, create 2 more of these, changing the names to `RedView` and `BlueView` and set the backgrounds appropriately to get the demo to work.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.GreenView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Width="30"
             Height="30">
    <Grid Background="Green"></Grid>
</UserControl>
```

What this example does when put together is creates colored squares on the `Canvas` of your shell based on the location of the mouse click. I think you should be able to take this and extend it to your needs.

Comment: i want to add multiplt view in the shellview.

Comment: @Kishore so add multiple VM properties and multiple 'ContentControl's to your view to match. Each VM property will be bound to the 'ContentControl' of the same name.

Comment: No, i cant add multiple controls, since i have nearly 50 views, and each view is added on a button click from ShellView. I was previously using canvas and add those usercontrol in that.

Comment: Oh I see what you are trying to do now. Are the items you add when the button is clicked all of the same type?

Comment: No, I will tell you, what i am trying to do. I am just trying to make a MDI like application using WPF MVVM. I am using UserControl instead of Window for my Views(Windows). So i thought to add my Views in a Canvas. So when a user click on a Stock button in ShellView, i have to open(add) StockView into my Canvas of ShellView, similarly if i click on Order button, i have to add OrdersView in canvas. thanks for your interest.

Comment: @KishoreJangid See the update to my answer which describes how you can achieve what you want.

Comment: please let me know. am i doing good by adding view to a canvas, instead of showing Window by WindowManager.

Comment: My View also has a close button inside another usercontrol place in the view. so when i click close it not removing from canvas. `UIHelper.GetVisualParent<Canvas>(this.Parent).Children.Remove(UIHelper.GetVisualParent<UserControl>(this.Parent));`

Comment: @KishoreJangid you'll need to pipe the close click through to the ShellViewModel and remove the item that sent the close from the BindableCollection Items.